# While applying for a potential internship, should I mention to HR that it was my friend (intern there) who gave me the HR's email address?

Tags: job-search, resume, human-resources, internship

I have obtained the email address of the HR from my senior (friend) interning at my dream company. As I am also keen to intern at the same company this coming May, in my writing of email to the HR, should I briefly mention about my friend who gave me the HR's email address? Really appreciate advice and thanks!

Comment: Do u mean asking my friend to request permission from the HR first? Sorrys I am new to the workplace

Comment: Alrights! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure to check with your friend if they're okay with using their name in your message. If it's okay, briefly mention it at the start of the email like this.

> Dear [HR Person Name],
>
> [Friend] provided me with your contact details, and I'm writing you to inquire about an internship at [Company Name].
>
> ...

The usefulness of this differs depending on whether it's a small company where most people know each other or a large multinational with 1000s of employees across multiple offices. In the second case, HR will probably not know who your friend is and it will not really add value.

Another option could be to ask your friend who works there to recommend you directly to HR. This way, that colleague vouches for you and that can definitely be advantageous.

Comment: Thanks alot! :)

Comment: @Elssie, Actually, I was an intern scanning resumes for a very large government organization, and in our case at least, I would check a tickbox if someone mentioned an employee by name or if the resume was forwarded from someone inside the organization (and this is not because we had a referral program, we did not have one). This tickbox in our database gave the resume higher priority and made it much more visible to hiring managers. The last thing we wanted was to be accused of losing resumes or screening out resumes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Looks like it is better to mention my friend (an intern working there) in the email if she is okay with it